# The argument type 'RemoteMessage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification

I had asked this question previously but could not get a solution. If I change the code String getRideRequestId(Map<String, dynamic> message) to String getRideRequestId(var message) the code it sends the message to the phone. It does not send the required rideDetails (Line 82,83 & 84).Iam looking to send the ride details as well. Please help me out here.

Here is the error log:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/Notifications/pushNotificationService.dart:17:48: Error: The argument type 'RemoteMessage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

- 'RemoteMessage' is from 'package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/remote_message.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.0.5/lib/src/remote_message.dart').
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message));
  ^
  lib/Notifications/pushNotificationService.dart:22:50: Error: The argument type 'RemoteMessage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
- 'RemoteMessage' is from 'package:firebase_messaging_platform_interface/src/remote_message.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.0.5/lib/src/remote_message.dart').
- 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
  retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message));

**Below is my code:**

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/carInfoScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/configMaps.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/mainScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/AllScreens/registrationScreen.dart';
import 'package:driver/DataHandler/appData.dart';

import 'AllScreens/loginScreen.dart';

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async
{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
DatabaseReference driversRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");
DatabaseReference newRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Requests");
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers").child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid).child("newRide");

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AppData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Driver',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? LoginScreen.idScreen : MainScreen.idScreen,
        routes: {
          RegistrationScreen.idScreen: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
          LoginScreen.idScreen: (context) => LoginScreen(),
          MainScreen.idScreen: (context) => MainScreen(),
          CarInfoScreen.idScreen: (context) => CarInfoScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**pushNotificationService.dart**

```
import 'package:driver/Models/rideDetails.dart';
import 'package:driver/configMaps.dart';
import 'package:driver/main.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

class PushNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialize(context) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;

      retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message));
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
      (RemoteMessage message) {
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message));
      },
    );
  }

  Future<String?> getToken() async {
    String? token = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    driversRef.child(currentFirebaseUser!.uid).child("token").set(token);

    print("Here is your token");
    print(token);

    firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("alldrivers");
    firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("allusers");
  }

  // String getRideRequestId(var message) {

  String getRideRequestId(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    String rideRequestId = "";

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      rideRequestId = message['data']['ride_request_id'];
    } else {
      rideRequestId = message['ride_request_id'];
    }
    return rideRequestId;
  }

  void retrieveRideRequestInfo(String rideRequestId) {
    newRequestRef.child(rideRequestId).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        double pickupLocationLat =
            double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['pickup']['latitude'].toString());
        double pickupLocationLng =
            double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['pickup']['longitude'].toString());
        String pickupAddress = dataSnapshot.value['pickup_address'].toString();

        double dropoffLocationLat =
            double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['dropoff']['latitude'].toString());
        double dropoffLocationLng =
            double.parse(dataSnapshot.value['dropoff']['longitude'].toString());
        String dropoffAddress =
            dataSnapshot.value['dropoff_address'].toString();

        String paymentMethod = dataSnapshot.value['payment_method'].toString();

        String rider_name = dataSnapshot.value["rider_name"].toString();
        String rider_phone = dataSnapshot.value["rider_phone"].toString();

        RideDetails rideDetails = RideDetails();
        rideDetails.ride_request_id = rideRequestId;
        rideDetails.pickup_address = pickupAddress;
        rideDetails.dropoff_address = dropoffAddress;
        rideDetails.pickup = LatLng(pickupLocationLat, pickupLocationLng);
        rideDetails.dropoff = LatLng(dropoffLocationLat, dropoffLocationLng);
        rideDetails.payment_method = paymentMethod;
        rideDetails.rider_name = rider_name;
        rideDetails.rider_phone = rider_phone;

        print("Information :: ");
        print(rideDetails.pickup_address);
        print(rideDetails.dropoff_address);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**rideDetails.dart**

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class RideDetails {
  String? pickup_address;
  String? dropoff_address;
  LatLng? pickup;
  LatLng? dropoff;
  String? ride_request_id;
  String? payment_method;
  String? rider_name;
  String? rider_phone;

  RideDetails({this.pickup_address,
    this.dropoff_address,
    this.pickup, this.dropoff,
    this.ride_request_id,
    this.payment_method,
    this.rider_name,
    this.rider_phone});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send an object of class `RemoteMessage` in a function that accepts `Map<String,dynamic>`. To send the correct format of data use this [reference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/)

Convert your RemoteMessage to Map and then send it again. If you want to send data of notification, you can send like this:

```
retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message.notification));
```

and then retrieve data in `getRideRequestId(Map<String, dynamic> message)`  using:

```
 messageOfTitle=message["title"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Monik. I have just changed the code you suggested. But the error The argument type 'RemoteNotification?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Map<String, still doesnt go away. It says 'notification' refers to a property so it couldn't be promoted. See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-property (remote_message.dart:75). I think I have mixed up the entire code. Could you put here the code in the right sequence, please. Thanks.I am quite new to flutter.

Comment: in my notifiction have custom properties that is not in `RemoteMessage` , its look like these ```notification
: 
body
: 
""
tag
: 
""
title: ""
:``` i have tag properties where its not in RemoteMessage , how i can convert them ? its tag properties has set on website

Comment: now i have solve by `toMap()` , where `RemoteMessage` have the class to json string then manipulation to other or `MyModel` .  **firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are following udemy course source code.
Here is solution. Change the getRiderRequestid function like below.

```
  String getRideRequestId(RemoteMessage message)
  {
    String rideRequestId = "";
    if(Platform.isAndroid)
    {
       rideRequestId = message.data['ride_request_id'] ; //message['data']['ride_request_id'];
    }
    else
    {
       rideRequestId = message.data['ride_request_id'];
    }

    return rideRequestId;
  }
```